# MultipleCompilationErrorsException in running Groovy script

Tags: soapui

I'm trying to access all nodes of my request in XML format using `XmlHolder` class with `getDomNodes` method and when I try it it getting this error.

Can somebody explain what does this mean?

My source code:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

log.info "hello !! welcome to " 
def holder = new XmlHolder(context.expand('${logIn - Request 1#request}') 
def allnodes = holder.getDomNodes("//LoginParameters_1")
```

The error I get:

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script15.groovy: 6: unexpected token: def @ line 6, column 1. def allnodes = holder.getDomNodes("//LoginParameters_1")throws org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected token: def @ line 6, column 1. at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:140) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:108) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:162) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:550)...

---

```
  import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder import          com.eviware.soapui.support.xml.XmlUtils          
  log.info "hello !! welcome to " xmlu= new XmlUtils() 
  holder= new XmlHolder(context.expand('${logIn - Request 1#request}'))
  i=0 
  for (nodes in holder.getDomNodes("//wsos:logIn")) {       if(xmlu.getNodeValue(nodes[i])=="?") 
   xmlu.setNodeValue(nodes[i],"") 
     i++; 
  }
```

is giving me below error:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj$ElementXobj.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [0] Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), item(int), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), wait(), grep(), getClass() error at line: 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException` are related with incorrect syntax in the code, in your specific case the problem is a missing closed parenthesis:

A `)` is missing to close `XmlHolder` declaration:

```
def holder = new XmlHolder(context.expand('${logIn - Request 1#request}')
```

Must be:

```
def holder = new XmlHolder(context.expand('${logIn - Request 1#request}'))
                                                                         ^ missing close
```

Comment: @kavitha nice to help you. If the answer solve your problem think about [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: sure ..will do.. can upls help me further

Comment: import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import com.eviware.soapui.support.xml.XmlUtils

log.info "hello !! welcome to "
xmlu= new XmlUtils()
 holder= new XmlHolder(context.expand('${logIn - Request 1#request}'))
i=0

for (nodes in holder.getDomNodes("//wsos:logIn"))
{
 if(xmlu.getNodeValue(nodes[i])=="?")
    xmlu.setNodeValue(nodes[i],"")
 
 i++;
}
 is giving me below error:

Comment: @kavitha If you've a different question, please create a new one with your new problem and add all required details, this way you'll have more chance to get an answer.

Comment: Should really make another post. Take away that semicolon after the i++